# Убрать рамку у каждого последнего элемента в ряду

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Имеется карточный интерфейс, который состоит из ***8 блоков***, и у каждого блока установлен `border-right: 1px.`

При разрешении ***320px*** в каждом ряду расположено по ***2 блока*** и у последнего элемента в ряду (т.е у каждого второго) этот `border` не нужен.

Можно было бы прописать

```
nth-child(2n) { border: none }
```

Но при разрешении ***768px*** в каждом ряду выстраивается уже ***4 блока***, и теперь `border:none` нужно давать каждому четвертому. При этом наследуется правило `nth-child(2n)`, из-за которого рамки не будет ни у каждого второго, ни у каждого четвертого блока.

Можно переопределить для данного разрешения

```
nth-child(2n) {border-right: 1px}
```

Но это будет очень хрупкое решение, так как если потребуется сделать 3 блока в ряду, то у каждого третьего блока в ряду рамка справа останется.

```css
.catalog-nav {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.catalog-nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.catalog-nav__item {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 128px;
  background-color: #d8edfe;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .catalog-nav {
    width: 768px;
  }
  
  .catalog-nav__item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="catalog-nav">
    <ul class="catalog-nav__list">
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">1</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">2</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">3</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">4</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">5</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">6</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">7</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">8</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Ну и что мешает описать так как надо при разрешении `768px`???  `@media`

Comment: @Air так я описывал эту ситуацию с учетом как раз таки media.

Comment: Я ни слова не вижу в вопросе о медиа и метки тем более...  Нажми кнопку править, в окне редактирования, нажми `<>` и вставь пример,  как что было реализовано... Так будет понятнее и быстрее получишь ответ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант 1. Для каждого брекпоинта аккуратно прописать в медиа-запросе, каким блокам правую границу надо убрать, а каким вернуть.

Вариант 2. Вообще не трогать правую границу блоков, а вместо этого задать для`.catalog-nav__list` отрицательный `margin-right` (как раз на ширину границы), а для `.catalog-nav` добавить свойство `overflow: hidden;`. Тогда «лишняя» граница самого правого блока будет попадать под правый край контейнера, и её не будет видно.

[image: схема решения]

Проверьте:

```css
.catalog-nav {
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;  /* прячем всё, что выходит за края */
}

.catalog-nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -1px 0 0;  /* отрицательный margin-right */
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.catalog-nav__item {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 128px;
  background-color: #d8edfe;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .catalog-nav {
    width: 768px;
  }
  
  .catalog-nav__item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="catalog-nav">
    <ul class="catalog-nav__list">
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">1</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">2</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">3</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">4</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">5</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">6</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">7</li>
        <li class="catalog-nav__item">8</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```